# На какой раздел устанавливать grub?

Tags: debian, grub, apt-get

Сервер у hetzner с debian.
В очередной раз сделал привычное apt-get upgrade, выдало такую ерунду:

[image: install grub]

Что делать то, какой раздел выбрать чтобы сервер не помер?

Answer (score 1):

md1 и md2 намекает на raid. Но рейд собирает уже ядро. Поэтому, ставить надо на sda/sdb. Если все правильно настроено, то лучше ставить на оба ( я так у себя на ноуте сделал). Но не нужно ставить на md1/md2 (если это рейд)

Comment: Как то я с перепугу не сообразил что можно было в саппорт написать. На одном сервере с Debian 6 посоветовали в /dev/md1. На втором сервере с Debian 7 сказали ставить в /dev/sda и /dev/sdb. И там и там рейд стоит. Собственно так и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

> If you're unsure which drive is designated as boot drive by your BIOS, it is often a good idea to install GRUB to all of them.

вольный перевод (с дополнением):

если вы не знаете, какий диск назначен загрузочным в вашем *bios*-е, неплохой идеей будет установить *grub* в *mbr* **всех** этих дисков.

из личного опыта: это действительно неплохая идея.

Comment: Скорее всего вы правы, grub не дурак. На одном сервере отказался ставиться в /dev/md1, сказал что не может этого сделать.